# Change style to android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu

Tags: android, styles, popupmenu

I'm trying to change the background to "android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu".

I think I've done everything I've found in Internet to change the background.

res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#888888</item> 
</style>
```

res/values-v14/styles.xml

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
</style>
<style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#888888</item> 
</style>
```

Of course I've set "CustomActionBarTheme" in the activity where the popup is shown.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

AppCompat `PopupMenu` ignores `android:popupMenuStyle` theme attribute.

Use `popupMenuStyle` theme attribute with AppCompat. Your `v14` styles then match your default styles, so you can remove them.

**res/values/styles.xml**

```xml
<resources>
  <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#888888</item> 
  </style>
</resources>
```

**<s>res/values-v14/styles.xml</s>**